# Laravel sharing information between service providers

Tags: laravel, service, laravel-4

I'm just wondering how I'd be able to share information between service providers?

Comment: What kind of information are you talking about ?

Answer (score 1):

Service Providers are, actually, Service Bootstrappers for your services, if you need to share information between them it's because you need your services to talk to each other, probably, so you do that via the Application IoC Container:

```
class Service1Provider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app['service1'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            return new Service1;
        });
    }

}

class Service2Provider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $service1 = $this->app['service1'];

        $this->app['service2'] = $this->app->share(function($app) use ($service1)
        {
            return new Service2($service1);
        });
    }

}
```